# C Program causing black screen on the console

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

So I was coding this program and after I was done, I tried to run it but for some reason nothing shows up on the console.  I went through the code multiple times and tried multiple ways of performing the same function, which is basically to keep on getting inputs from the user until he/she enters 0, then display the largest and second largest number, and if the user enters 0 and there are no numbers available then continue checking.  I think may be there is an infinite loop or some other problem with it.  Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void main()
{
int input,z;
int large,small,counter=0;
bool a=false;

while (1){


 if(scanf("%d\n",&input)>0)
 {
     small=input;
     counter++;

     if(small>large)
     {
         z=small;
         small=large;
         large=z;

     }
 }
 else if(scanf("%d\n",&input)<0)
 {
     printf("Please enter a positive value\n");
 }
 else if(scanf("%d\n",&input)==0)
 {
     if(small>0 && large>0)
     {
        printf("There are in total %d positive integers entered",counter);
        printf("The largest number is %d, while the second largest is %d", large,small);
        a=true;
        break;
     }
     else
     {
         printf("You have to enter atleast two positive integers");
     }
 }
}
}
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `large` is not initialized when you compare it to `small`.

Answer (score 1):

If you walk carefully through the logic of your program, you'll see it doesn't make sense. For example, if a number is entered, you never print anything.

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf` function doesn't return the input, it returns *how many numbers it read*.

Since your code reads numbers one at a time, `scanf` will always return `1`, causing an infinite loop.

To fix this, hoist the `scanf` call outside the branching code:

```
while (1) {
    scanf("%d", &input);

    if (input > 0) ...
    else if (input < 0) ...
    else ...
}
```

There are more bugs in your code (Rohan pointed out one of them) but this should solve the black screen.

Comment: That's exactly what I did the first time I programmed it, and I just tried it again, and I am still getting the black screen.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you check the value entered, you're doing another scanf() or trying to read a new value instead of checking the value of the number that was entered. And the value you're checking is the return value of scanf(), but the number that's entered is actually stored in your "input" variable. So yes, there are a few things going on here, but you're essentially in an infinite loop because the entered values aren't getting read or evaluated properly.

The C function scanf() doesn't take a newline. Instead use:

```
scanf("%d", &input);
```

Also, initialize your "large" variable to 0 when you define it (it's value is not 0 and will give you unpredictable results):

```
int large = 0, small, counter = 0;
```

What you want to do is ONLY one scanf() at the top of your while loop to read in a number. After that, your if's should be testing the value of "input":

while (1) 
{

```
scanf("%d", &input);

if (input > 0)   /* positive number entered */
{
  /* do something */

} else if (input < 0) /* negative number entered */
{

  /* print error */

} else /* no need to test value since it must be 0 at this point */

  /* do stuff */
}
```

}

Happy C coding! ;-)

Comment: Once again I have tried this, but for some reason I get the same black screen.

Comment: If by "black screen" you mean it's blank as in nothing is printed, you'd be correct because you have no printf() before the scanf() asking the user to enter a number. Make the changes as noted above by me, and Lambda Fairy, and add a printf("enter number: "); before the scanf(). You'll find that it works as intended from your original question. Run it and play around with it, entering positive and negative numbers and finally 0 and you'll see. I played around with and tested it before posting a reply to your question.

Comment: By black screen i mean that even when i try to type something into the console I can't.  I added a printf statement and made the changes outlined by you and lambda fairy but i still have a problem where i can't enter anything into the console.

Comment: Hmm. That's strange, but it's not the code. I copied and pasted your code, made my changes, compiled (gcc) and ran it a Windows cmd window. It must be the "console" tool you're using or your environment. Are you seeing the printf() value? When you enter a number and hit return, does the print scroll up? Or is there absolutely no movement with the screen? What's your environment, compiler and console tool?

Comment: I am using code blocks, and no I can't input anything or see anything on the console.